# How to get results after submit form with PhantomJS?

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to get results from a simple form using PhantomJS. I'm using jQuery but don't work. I have this HTML:

```php
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhantomJS!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="frm">
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" />
<input type="submit" value="Publicar" id="btn-submit" />
</form>

Your name is <span id="nombrez"><?php if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) { echo $_POST['nombre'];} ?></span>

</body>
</html>
```

And this Javascript code:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/phantom/', function() {
  page.includeJs("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {

      $('#nombre').val('Fabian');
    document.forms[0].submit();
   });

    page.onLoadFinished = function(){

    console.log($("#nombrez").html());
    phantom.exit();

    };  


  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page.onLoadFinished` must not be called inside of `page.evaluate`, but inside the main PhantomJS script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(){

    var html = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.getElementById("nombrez").innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(html);
    phantom.exit();

};  

page.open('http://localhost/phantom/', function() {
    page.includeJs("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {

        $('#nombre').val('Fabian');
            document.forms[0].submit();
        });
    });
});
```

However `page.onLoadFinished` fires every time a page is done loading and with this implementation phantom will exit the first the time page  is loaded, even before the form is submitted.

You need to implement some check to distinguish between the first and the second load of the page. For example, if return `html` variable is empty it means that we haven't submitted page yet.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just added this to your code and does it works: 
if(html != "") {console.log(html);phantom.exit();}